# How to apply tile to specifics cordinates and size?

Tags: imagemagick

This is what I want to do:

1- I have this image (transparent on the center)

[image: bg]

2- I have this "pattern"

[image: pattern]

3- I want to apply this pattern to a specific X and Y and also specify the size of the repitition. The expected result should look something like this:

[image: result]

Do you know how I can accomplish that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create the textured rectangle then place it over the top of the circle using composite.

```
convert circle.png \( -size 88x61 tile:texture.png \) -geometry +50+63 -composite result.png
```

[edit] If you want the texture underneath, you could do this:

```
convert -size 200x200 xc:transparent
-page +50+63 -size 88x61 tile:texture.png
-page +0+0 circle.png
-layers flatten result.png
```

I think that's self explanatory but 88x61 is the size of the rectangle, 200x200 is the size of the circle image, +50+63 is the location you want it to be placed at, circle.png is the transparent circle image, and texture.png is the seamless pattern.

I tested this with your images and it worked, but the pattern you included doesn't seem to be the full seamless version so it didn't come out looking exactly like your expected result.

Comment: Hi frostyterrier, it worked, but I needed that the texture layer goes behind the original image. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Hi frosty. Thank you for your answer. It is working now. I also posted another question that is killing me all day long. Do you mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071640/how-to-rotate-a-composite-image-with-fixed-center. Thank you in advance.