# How to rotate a composite image with fixed center?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So, I have this background image:

[image: bg.png]

And I have a 1px x 1px image that I want to overlay on that. If I run:

```
convert bg.png \( -size 80x240 -background none -rotate 30 -geometry +120+88 tile:red.png \) -composite result.png
```

I get this:

[image: result.png]

But I want to rotate it with fixed center. The expected result should be something like this:

[image: expected result.png]

Do you know how can I accomplish that?

Thank you.

Comment: I have played with this but haven't found a solution yet. I found that using -distort SRT I could get it to be rotated around the center, but it was then cropped inside the original shape and I couldn't find a way to adjust the viewport to make it all show. Honestly, if this was my project, and depending on the shapes I was rotating and the precision I needed, I might just try cutting my x coordinate in half to get it closer to being centered. I know, that's terrible :)

Comment: I made some test and I was able to get the final result by creating an image with the rotation I needed, and adapting the gemotry so the center point stands exactly in the center point of the non-rotated image. It worked, but I didn't wanted to waste my server CPU that much. Do you think that this cropping problem could be solved if you create an image of the same size of the background before composing them?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I hadn't used SRT before today.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the comment by @frostyterrier I think his problem is he needs +distort and is using -distort?

This page should help: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#srt

Rotate an image and have a transparent background

```
convert input.jpg -background none -virtual-pixel background +distort ScaleRotateTranslate 30 output.png
```

Comment: Thanks, Bonzo, but I wasn't able to position the overlay in the desired location. Were you able to do that?

Comment: I had tried +distort and it came out looking like the original image (rotated from the corner) :(

Comment: @robertoki I did try it with your images and get the same result as both of you - are you sure the -geometry +120+88 is what you want robertoki? Have you tried rotating an image to confirm it rotates about its center with my code example?